# For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $0<e-\left(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}\right)<\frac{1}{n!n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, real-numbers, factorial

I'm stucked in this problem: For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that

$$0<e-\left(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}\right)<\frac{1}{n!n}$$ From this, prove $e$ is irrational.

I don't know how to prove $e-\left(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}\right)<\frac{1}{n!n}$. I already used induction, but it didn't work. I don't really mind about $e$ being irrational, just the inequality. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The title is misleading. It should be something like "Prove that [insert equation you wrote above]"

Comment: What is your definition of $e$?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The usual one. $e=lim\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.

Comment: @JulianNeira:  the definition of $e$ comes at the stage you want to define $a^b$ over the reals.  There are at least four different ways to approach it.  You need the natural log function, so you can define it as the integral of $\frac 1x$.  You can define $e^x$ from the Taylor series.  You can use yours, but usually it is $e^a$ on the left and $\frac an$. I forget the fourth.  Once you choose one, you prove the others as theorems.  Having done that, it doesn't matter where you started, so we forget it, but for questions like this it is important because you may not have the others available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the Taylor expansion of $e$, namely,
$$e = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}.$$
From this, one can deduce
$$e - \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1+k)!}, \quad n=0,1,\dots.$$
This automatically provides the lower bound. To get the upper bound, realize that, for each $k\geq 1$, $$(n+1+k)! = (n+1+k)\cdots (n+2)(n+1)! > (n+1)!(n+1)^k,$$
hence
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^{-k},$$
which is a geometric series with a known formula. Simplifying this geometric series will yield the desired upper bound.

Source: Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, 3d ed, pp 65.

Comment: I suppose that Taylor expansion is forbidden here.